# Make versions:update-child-modules execute on release:prepare

Tags: maven

Is there a way to trigger `versions:update-child-modules` on `release:prepare` in Maven?

[Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) claims 'Executes by direct invocation only.' but I want to use this to force the modules in a reactor build to have the right versions. Some modules are only included for certain profiles, and this manually fixes it but it would be so much nicer to have it as part of the release process.

Comment: Why would you like to run `release:prepare` via `versions:update-child-modules` cause `release:prepare` will do updates on the pom etc. ?

Comment: It doesn't update the modules that aren't included in the build for the profile selected, leaving them out of sync and causing the next build to fail. But.. I can call versions:update-child-modules with all the profiles to fix this. If I force the release to fix the versions before building, the problem might go away (if I can also force it to update all possible profiles).

Comment: To me this is a missing feature. It is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-843. The release plugin should update all modules, not just those in the reactor.

Comment: Modules which are in a profile are from my point of view a problem...cause the question is why modules are included/excluded via profile? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: The project has a compatibility layer to adapt between multiple versions of the platform API it is being deployed to (Adobe AEM). Different versions have different underlying APIs and are not compatible, so we've solved the problem using an abstraction layer. We pull the right version in (along with the right dependencies) using Maven Profiles. Overall it works, but the release plugin wrecks the version numbers. I want to force-align them on 'release:prepare', solving this completely.

Comment: @RobertScholte Nice find, that's exactly the problem. Sadly it's quite an old bug so I doubt it will be fixed.

Comment: @antonyh it is open source. If you can provide a patch, I'm willing to have a look at it :) I've started to rewrite the plugin, which should make it easier to fix issues like this one (understanding stuff outside of the reactorProjects which might need to be changed too).

Comment: I'll take a look, it might even be fun to work on this to help improve it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use profiles to adapt to build-time context, not run-time context, and
>   not (with rare exceptions) to produce alternative versions of your
>   artifact

-- https://dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices

The reason this doesn't work is it's an abuse of Maven. What I really wanted & needed is to build all the projects in the reactor build, so they all get released and versioned properly. The build-time context doesn't change in my case, so profiles shouldn't be excluding modules.

In essence this meant removing the `<modules>` from the profiles, letting the reactor build everything, and using the profile to control the included dependencies for the target platform API.

This is as @khmarbaise suggested in the comments above, "Modules which are in a profile are from my point of view a problem". Wise words.

As for why I couldn't trigger `versions:update-child-modules` on `release:prepare` -  it's not possible to alter a POM that is already being processed. Either the change is ignored, or it causes Maven to malfunction. I tried adding it as a plugin execution, and as an 'exec' task to run Maven as a separate process, and it refused to work. I tried multiple phases, including `clean` and `pre-clean`, with no joy.

It seems the only way to change this would be to resolve https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-843  and enable the release plugin to update all the modules in all profiles.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I ended up removing the parent from the child module, and forcing it to set the version thus:

```
PROJECT_VERSION=`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version |grep -e -SNAPSHOT$`
mvn -B -DnewVersion=$PROJECT_VERSION -f foo_module/ versions:set
mvn -B -DnewVersion=$PROJECT_VERSION -f bar_module/ versions:set
```

...then committing this update to the SCM, as part of the Jenkins build. I'm not super-happy about this though, because now the release is only guaranteed to work in the one Jenkins job and isn't readily portable.

It's also changed the project hierarchy, another side effect.